# Make Assembly Load Options unique to each assembly in Siemens NX 12

Tags: modeling, cad, siemens, siemens-nx

I have a few assemblies I'm working on. For the most part, each assembly is self-contained in its own folder (assembly file and part files). However, there are a number of common parts that are stored in their own separate folder. When I import these into my assemblies using the Add Component feature, it works fine. However, once I closed the assembly and opened it back up, the common parts were not found and not loaded. I did some Bing-ing and ended up changing the Assembly Part Options so that the assembly folder and the various folders I saved common parts to were all listed under "From Search Folders". That works great, as long as I'm only ever working on that assembly. However, when I opened another assembly again, I noticed that that one also had the same issue. I figured no problem, I'll just do the same thing. When I went to do that, I discovered that the Assembly Load Options paths were by default the same I had set for the first assembly. Is there a way of having these path lists be unique to certain assemblies? I don't want to have to add a new folder to this list every time I make a new assembly and eventually end up with some insanely long path list.

Thanks!